# AudioQueueStart is returning error code -50

Tags: ios, swift, audiotoolbox, audioqueueservices

Start audio recording giving error sometimes and below method returns error

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)" UserInfo=
>         status = AudioQueueStart(_state.queue, NULL);

**Followed below steps for recording audo -**

1. **Created a new audio queue for recording audio data.**

   `status = AudioQueueNewInput(&_state.dataFormat,
                                   AudioInputCallback,
                                   &_state,
                                   CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                                   kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
                                   0,
                                   &_state.queue);`
2. **Sets an audio queue property value.**

   `status = AudioQueueSetProperty(_state.queue,kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering,&on,sizeof(on));`
3. **an audio queue to allocate a buffer.**

   `status = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(_state.queue, buffer_size, &_state.buffers[i]);`
4. **Assigns a buffer to an audio queue for recording or playback.**

   `status = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer (_state.queue, _state.buffers[i], 0, NULL);`
5. **Added a listener callback for a property.**

   `status = AudioQueueAddPropertyListener(_state.queue,
                                              kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning,
                                              recordingRunningChangedCallback,
                                              &_state);`
6. **Begins playing or recording audio.**

   `status = AudioQueueStart(_state.queue, NULL);`

And last steps returns error with

> error code -50

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same issue. For whatever reason calling `AudioQueueStart` twice did the trick for me:

```
status = AudioQueueStart(_state.queue, NULL);
if (status == -50) {
    status = AudioQueueStart(_state.queue, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As can be found [here](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-50), this is [`AVAudioSessionErrorCodeBadParam`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessionerrorcode/avaudiosessionerrorcodebadparam).

So apparently one of the parameters you specify is invalid or a parameter is missing.

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30428298/1971013) help perhaps?

As setting up audio in iOS is rather intricate, I advice you to start from working sample code, or to follow a decent tutorial. From own experience I can tell that it's easy to miss something and get errors like this.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because my `AVAudioSession` was not configured the right way.

If you only have an output queue, you need to configure your `AVAudioSession` with the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` category. Here is some code:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSString *category = AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback;
NSString *mode = AVAudioSessionModeDefault;
NSUInteger options = AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers;
NSError *err = nil;
[session setCategory:category mode:mode options:options error:&err];
```

If you want output and input at the same time you can do the same with `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`